# renderDataTable doesn't display characters properly

Tags: r, shiny

How can I get renderDataTable to correctly display my characters (é,ñ) read from a .csv file?

The rendered table displays question marks in both columns.

```
server = function(input, output, session)
  {
       cal <<- read.csv(calendar_name, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8")
       output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(cal, rownames = F))
      }
```

my csv file:

test1,test2
é,ñ

Answer (score 1):

It must be your file I suspect, perhaps you set the wrong encoding?

making a table in excel 1,2,3,4 and your text strings in row 2, then export as csv with unicode UTF-8 works fine for me.

using <<- is not the way to go by the way. That assigns the data to the environment 1 level up from your app, in this case the global environment. Instead you want to do local assignment inside render blocks, or even better, outside in reactive({}) objects or reactiveValues()

This works fine for me:

```
library('shiny')
library('DT')

ui <- fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput('table1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   DataX <- reactive({ setwd('D:/')
     mydata <- read.csv('Dummyfile.csv', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8") 
                      mydata})

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(DataX(), rownames = F))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Mark,  I am in Windows 10 if that matters. When I change the file to unicode the characters are displayed as "<U+00E9>","<U+00F1>" in the .csv.  But they are displayed that way in the rendered datatable as well.

Comment: can you share the file somehow with a downloadable link?

Comment: well of course they would be displayed like <U=00E9> etc because that is what they ARE in the file you just send me. If I open it with notepad I literally see this: "","test1","test3"
"1","<U+00E9>","<U+00F1>" : random space, and a random 1.... 
Try it with this file instead for me  https://www.justbeamit.com/yy32i

Comment: p.s. your OP stated that your file contains the actual characters, not unicode tags

Comment: can't reach  justbeamit.com/yy32i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190962/discussion-between-charles-stangor-and-mark).